# Upload `POST`local Revit files to BIM 360 using forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I have a small question regarding Upload local Revit files to BIM 360 using forge,  instead of open files using Revit and sync with BIM 360. I would like to build `Using web interface` and upload the files the idea behind that to save time because we have a lot of files... so if every time I want to sync the Revit project it will take a long time. I am not sure if the tutorial does what I am looking for:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/publish-model/

---

note that I am basically using JS and node JS, and the RVT files on the network location. I already followed the tutorial on learning forge and I managed to access BIM360 same at the tutorial,  so now to POST the OBJ to OSS in specific folders.

I hope you get my point just to save time as I mentioned earlier instead open Revit project and Sync. I think we can  put `POST` all the files at ones to BIM 360 using my own application or website 

Answer (score 0):

It sounds the other tutorial should be what you are looking for:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/
It explains how to upload a local file as a resource item to the project such as version item in the folder of BIM 360.  Could you check if it helps?

It is also feasible to transfer the file from your cloud server. After getting the file stream, upload it to storage of BIM 360 (similar to step 4 in the above link shows ).

Please let us know if there is any further question.

Comment: Hi Xiaodong, thank you so much for replying to me I have a question before start using the API! do you think in this solution will reference the RVT files (OBJ) without using Revit in order to do a collaboration?
OR it works the same way when open bim360 and click on upland files(works just like storge)? I just want to skip this part  https://youtu.be/3Xw3Fs6mvBs and replace with Forge

Comment: Hi Abed, sorry for my late response. I do not get what does mean by 'will reference the RVT files (OBJ) without using Revit in order to do a collaboration', but as to 'it works the same way when open bim360 and click on upload files(works just like storge)', I can say it is similar, while as I know Revit UI has its own desktop API to manage this workflow. Anyway, I wanted to say, you can upload local Revit file to BIM 360 by Forge API, as mentioned in my last reply.